# How can I get the DOM element from an Om DIV?

Tags: clojurescript, om

I am using Clojurescript Om and I need to access the underlying DOM element (so that I can set offsetTop to 0) on one of the DIVs contained in a component. How can I get access to this element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`get-node`](https://github.com/omcljs/om/wiki/Documentation#get-node). There is an example available [here](https://github.com/omcljs/om/blob/b549554964fe5b53189222e97e77fc2db34aebd6/examples/sortable/src/core.cljs#L90).

Note that the component must be already mounted in order to access its DOM element, therefore you should invoke `get-node` in one of the Om lifecycle methods that are invoked after the component is mounted (e.g. `did-mount`).

If you are using om.next, then you should use the [`node`](https://github.com/omcljs/om/wiki/Documentation-(om.next)#node) function instead.